# sap.m.PlanningCalendar - How to display hour in 24-hour format?

Tags: sapui5

I am using a planning calendar where I am displaying the appointments. I am showing the calendar from 7AM to 5PM. But I want the Hour format to be in 24-hour format, like after 12PM it should be 13, 14, 15.. likewise.

Answer (score 0):

<s>It seems like hour format for planning calendar depends on browser locale. For example for me (Europe, Poland) hours are in 24hours format.</s>

It is related to Launchpad settings:

You can set it default in transaction SU01 tab defaults for selected user or You could do massive change in SU10. If You need more information You could find it in 2404186 SAP Note launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002504186

Comment: i tried that to. i changed my system time to 24hours format, but still it didn't work. 
we are using Fiori launchpad. If the fiori launchpad timings is in 24  hours format then it shows in 24 hours format. if the fiori launchpad timings is in 12  hours format  it shows in 12 hours format. I want it to be by default in 24 hours format without depending on the fiori launchpad

Comment: Nope, my browser/OS locale is 12H, but I see calendar in 24H format.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most ideal answer, but the 12/24 can be influenced by the locale. For example, adding the URL parameter sap-locale=ES (or sap-language) would use the 24 hour setting because that's how the locale is defined. You could also do it by calling:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setFormatLocale()
```

before rendering with a locale (as string) which uses 24hr.

It may be possible to extend locales to have a special one that has a 24hr format, but the rest of the settings being the same, but I couldn't find any examples of how to do this, and it's not immediately apparent to me.

edit: if English is necessary, locales such as "en_GB", "en_IE" or "en_ZA" may be used.

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't work for us, my Fiori launchpad is set to 24hr as well as in SU01 backend system, but the Planning Calendar still shows 12PM.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry... First post here. Where should I have posted the comment?

Comment: WTH... What is i